# How to make the number 49?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

You've to start with $1$ and can use each of the following operations at most once.
You can do the following in any order you like:

1) Add $2$.

2) Add $3$.

3) Add $5$.

4) Multiply $2.$

5) Multiply $3.$

6) Multiply $5$.

How to make the number $49?$

Answer (score 15):

You can do:

> +3 [->4], x5 [->20], +2 [->22], x2 [->44], +5 [->49].

Comment: Not even 20 minutes :p

Comment: @Avi It is fairly easy to solve quickly if you do it backwards, starting from 49 and working back to 1.

Comment: It looks like the question OP asked is from the ongoing competetion https://in.bricsmath.com/students/tours/trial/tasks/trial_tour_card_1. Although it is still a trial round , the site provides no answer or explanation to the solution and I believe that outside help should not be provided as long as the competition is active.

Comment: Ah, crap. I did _wonder_ whether it was an original puzzle or not, but it seemed like the sort of thing the OP could easily have made up. Maybe we need to have a policy of just _always_ asking that question for new PSE users unless it's super-duper-obvious. The bricsmath site says "The results of the trial round do not affect the main round." so I don't think it does much harm to leave this here; anyone looking up the answer here rather than solving it themselves isn't harming anyone _else_.

Answer (score 9):

As @Jaap commented, the simplest way to move forward is to

> start at 49 and invert the listed operations.

So let's go spelunking!

> The most obvious thing is that no division step can take place first. Therefore, we must start by subtracting.

Subtracting by 2 is a non-starter, since this generates 47.

> This limits us again to a subtraction step, making 44 [-3] or 42 [-5].
>  44 goes to 39 [-5], which only grants 13 [/3] and then ends, or 22 [/2], which also ends after 17 [-5]. From this, we realize that hitting 44 with [-2 and -3] or 39 with all subtraction steps is an effort in futility, so we'll avoid those chains.
>  42 goes to 39 [-3] (covered above), 21 [/2], or 14 [/3]
>  21 goes to 18 only [-3], which only grants 6 [/3] and ends.
>  14 goes to 7 [/2], which only grants 4 [-3] and ends.

Now starting with subtracting by 3,

> 46 goes to 44 [-2], 41 [-5], or 23 [/2]. 
>  41 immediately ends, as a prime and as a direct result of the only possible remaining move [-2] yielding 39 with all subtraction steps. As such, we'll ignore 41 if it comes up again.
>  23 goes to 18 [-5] or 21 [-2], which ends after 2 steps: 7 [/3] and 2 [-5]. So close!
>  18 goes to 16 [-2], which ends since we only have [/3] or [/5] left, or 6 [/3], which also ends with [/5] left.

And finally subtracting by 5 for our first step.

44 is a decent starting point, since we still have [-2] and [-3] available. Let's take this a little bit slower, since this is likely to yield a lot more potential steps.

> [/2] gives 22, which goes to 20 [-2] or 19 [-3].
>  20 goes to 17 [-3], which ends with only [/3] and [/5] left, or 4 [/5]. The only feasible move is [-3], which gives 1. Success! [/3] left over.
>  19 goes to 17 [-2], which is ruled out above.
>  [-2] gives 42, which is the same case as in the first description. 
>  [-3] gives 41. No thanks.

Therefore, the only feasible solution is

> -5, /2, -2, /5, -3. Or, going from 1 to 49, +3, *5, +2, *2, +5.

Looks like @Gareth really knew what he was doing!

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
<script>

a=[];
st=6;
for (let i=0;i<st;i++) {
a.push(new Array(st).fill(0));
a[a.length-1][i]=st;
}
while (st>1) {
b=[];
st--;
for (let i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
tmA=[];
for (let j=0;j<a[i].length;j++) if (a[i][j]==0) tmA.push(j);
for (let j=0;j<st;j++) {
var nwA=a[i].slice(0);
nwA[tmA[j]]=st;
b.push(nwA);
}
}
a=b.slice(0);
}

x=['+2)','+3)','+5)','*2)','*3)','*5)'];
c=[];
for (i=0;i<720;i++) {
str='((((((1';
for (j=0;j<6;j++)
str+=x[a[i][j]-1];
c.push(str);
}

for (i=0;i<720;i++) {j=eval(c[i]);if (j==49) console.log(j);console.log(i+' : '+c[i]+' = '+j);}

</script>
```

proves that there are no solutions using all 6 operations.

Changing `st` to $5$ in the first part, and the last part of the code to:

```
x=['+2)','+3)','+5)','*2)','*3)','*5)'];
c=[];
for (let k=0;k<6;k++) {
for (let i=0;i<120;i++) {
str='(((((1';
for (let j=0;j<5;j++)
str+=x[a[i][j]-1];
c.push(str);
}
x.unshift(x.pop());
}
```

finds:

> (((((1+3)*5)+2)*2)+5) = 49

as the only solution with 5 operations.

Comment: No, you cannot use brackets on the numbers used in the operations. (2 ADD 5) is not allowed.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in python (because https://www.xkcd.com/353/)

```
import itertools

ops = []
ops.append(lambda t: t + 2)
ops.append(lambda t: t + 3)
ops.append(lambda t: t + 5)
ops.append(lambda t: t * 2)
ops.append(lambda t: t * 3)
ops.append(lambda t: t * 5)


for r in range(len(ops)):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(ops, r):
        for p in itertools.permutations(subset):
            res = 1
            rec = []
            for op in p:
                res = op(res)
                rec.append(ops.index(op))
            if res == 49:
                print(res, rec)
```

This prints:

```
49 [1, 5, 0, 3, 2]
```

Where `49` is the result, and `[1, 5, 0, 3, 2]` is the list of operations applied (to 1) (indices starting from 0 of course).